# Load Mysql table from bottom to top

Tags: php, html, mysql

i don't know a lot of php but, i have the following code, it will load all images from the top of the table to the bottom, can i invert this process? load from de bottom to top? I need the ordest lines to be loaded first...

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("bravo");
    $res=mysql_query("select * from coisas");

?>
<div>
<?php
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    echo "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";

    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: So add an ORDER BY clause to your SQL statement

Comment: Please, **stop using** `mysql_query`. Where did you learn how to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table have one identifier column you can do that (assuming id is the identifier column name):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("bravo");
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coisas ORDER BY id DESC");

?>
<div>
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

echo "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">";

} 
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the error? Do you have the column 'id' in your database table?

Comment: sorry, the name of the table was not coisas, was musicas, i just change it and work perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Done... And to load all the images randomly?

Comment: amazing! I am increasingly interested in the php

Comment: is not php ... is mysql ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Baker correctly say, let SQL do it for you with a `ORDER BY`.

If you still want to do this in PHP, use this snippet of code:

```
<?php
    $html = '';
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
      html = "<img src=\"{$row['imagem']}\">".$html;
    }
    echo $html;
?>
```

This will concatenate your current (of the loop) fetched array entry with previous one. So, the first will be concatenated before the last (read it as inversed order).

Moreover, **don't use `msql_*`** as those functions are deprecated. Use `msqli_*` or `PDO` instead

PS.: This code is your code revisited, if there is any error (in fetching array, connection or so) please correct it your own: I only give you a pointer